# Lists and map orderings

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, tolist

In Scala, if we have `List[(Char, Int)]` ordered by the first element of each pair, does converting to a map via `toMap` preserve the ordering?

If so, does converting the resulting map back to list via `toList` preserve ordering?

Answer (score 5):

No, `Map` (and `Set`) are not ordered. You can check this using Scala's interactive interpreter (REPL):

```
scala> val elems = List('a'->1, 'b'->2, 'c'->3, 'd'->4, 'e'->5)
elems: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4), (e,5))

scala> elems.toMap.toList
res8: List[(Char, Int)] = List((e,5), (a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4))
```

However, `scala.collection` does provide a `SortedMap`, which might be what you are looking for, though I haven't used this implementation yet.

---

**Edit:** Actually, there's an even more fundamental problem with this conversion: Because you cannot have duplicate keys in a map, you are not just losing guarantees on the ordering, but also, your list may have less elements after the conversion. Consider this:

```
scala> val elems = List('a'->1, 'a'->2)
elems: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,1), (a,2))

scala> elems.toMap.toList
res9: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,2))
```

Comment: "your list may have less elements after the conversion" Quite correct generally. Since I will bet this is a question arising from a Coursera Scala course, for that exercise, the keys will be unique :)

Answer (score 1):

As aforementioned, `Map` and `Set` have no ordering. Yet consider `TreeMap` which preserves ordering over its keys; for instance

```
val a = List(('z', 1), ('a', 4), ('b', 4))
a: List[(Char, Int)] = List((z,1), (a,4), (b,4))

val b = collection.immutable.TreeMap(a:_*)
b: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Char,Int] = Map(a -> 4, b -> 4, z -> 1)
```

**Update**

Note that

```
for ( (k,v) <- b ) yield k
res: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Char] = List(a, b, z)
```